# creating webcam chat from scratch

Tags: flash, flex4

I need to create a webcam chat which i intend to use in my website. 
It will allow two or more persons to video chat through their webcams.

I want to develop the webcam chat from the scratch. I have no idea
which software to use.  I did a thorough search for this topic and all
i got is adobe flash with some actionscript is required to build it.

I am a complete newbie in this but i want to learn from beginning.

Please help.

thanks

Comment: flex is definitely your friend
just google "flex video chat" and "flex video chat tutorial"
i was a newbie once in actionscript but i learnt a lot from the tutorials
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read some ActionScript tutorials. You need to walk before you can run. This kind of application will require a wide range of knowledge of Flash, AS and general programming skills.

Begin with some basic "hello world" code, then learn the language fully, then move onto bigger and better things.

Here's a good place to start: http://www.actionscript.org/resources/categories/Tutorials/

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain their reasoning?

Comment: @Upvoter is here to save the day!